# Python VSCode formatOnSave with black not working in WSL

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using WSL2 to work on some Python project, but black is not auto-formatting in VSCode (Remote - WSL).

System info:

- Base system: Windows 11 Pro x64
- WSL2 system: Ubuntu-22.04-LTS
- `settings.json` path in WSL: `/home/<user>/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json`

My `settings.json` looks like:

```json
{
  // Python linting and formatting customizations..
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.flake8Args": ["--max-line-length=100", "--ignore=E501"],
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "python.formatting.blackArgs": ["--line-length", "100"],
  "[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
}
```

This same settings works on my Windows 11 system. In local Windows, whenever I create a virtual environment for a python project and save a python file, vscode automatically asks me to install `flake8` and `black` in the venv. But nothing of the sort happens in WSL.

Even if I install `black` in WSL Python venv, it does not auto-format the Python code; and there are no logs related to `black` visible in either `Output > Python` or `Output > Log (Main)` tab.

But manual formatting works after I install `black` in venv:

```
(venv) asif@MSI:~/vscode/myproject/$ black app_pkg/models.py 
reformatted app_pkg/models.py

All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.
```

**Note:** I even tried adding `"python.formatting.blackPath": "./venv/bin/black"` to `settings.json` file, but it didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** As suggested, I have these two settings enabled in my system,
Format on save applied universally:
[image: format on save settings]
Python code formatter set as `black`:
[image: Python default formatter settings]

Still I am unable to make the Python `formatOnSave` work in VSCode-WSL.

Answer (score 0):

> But manual formatting works after I install black in venv

It can be seen that black can work.Now let's set up automatic formatting for vscode:

First open the settings of vscode, search for `format on save`, and then check it. Set this step, and the code will be automatically typeset every time the file is saved.

[image]

Then search `Python formatting provider` and select **black**.

[image]

Comment: I have tried these settings too. The only difference between this one and my settings is that I switched on auto-format only for python. I tried moving that part outside to auto-format all type of code too, but that did not work. Please check the edit.

Comment: Please try to reinstall vscode.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to install python first in your WSL.

had the same issue. now it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).